# How to install a library on a Databricks Automated Cluster

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks

I'm running a Job on an Databricks Automated cluster, but the job keeps on failing because it needs the following library:

com.microsoft.azure:azure-sqldb-spark:1.0.2

However, the Cluster needs to be running in order install the library, but the cluster will never run because it fails ... kind of catch-22 situation.

Therefore, can someone let me know how to install a library on an Databricks Automated cluster

[image]

As you can see from the image, there isn't a selection to add any library

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The packages/libraries can be loaded as dependency in the Job settings.

**Here are the steps to load dependency in automated clusters.**

**Step1:** Download the library from the maven repository.

**Example:** I have download (`com.microsoft.azure:azure-sqldb-spark:1.0.2`) jar file from the maven repository.

[image]

**Step2:** Upload the library to the Databricks workspace.

Go to **Workspace** => **Create** => **Library** => **upload** the previously download jar file => Click **create**.

Now you have jar file in your workspace.

[image]

**Step3:** Go to the created job add the library as the dependent library for the job.

Go to the **job created** => **Click on Dependent Libraries: Add** => **Select the library** which is available in the workspace => Click **OK**.

[image]